# undefined method `input' for "NoMethodError in Revisers#new "

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

I'm trying to get this form to work.  `Revisers` has a `has_one` relationship to `User`.

**new.html:**

```html
<div class="container">

  <%= form_for @reviser, url: new_user_reviser_path(user_id: current_user.id) do |f| %>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="div.col-md-4 select">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>dsd</label>
    <%= f.input :description %>
   </div>
    
   </div> 
  </div>
             <%= f.submit "Become Adviser", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Error Log:**

```
Rendered revisers/_form.html.erb (30.8ms)
  Rendered revisers/new.html.erb within layouts/application (31.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007faf35829f10>):
    11:             <div class="div.col-md-4 select">
    12:             <div class="form-group">
    13:                 <label>dsd</label>
    14:                 <%= f.input :description %>
    15:             </div>
    16:                 
    17:             </div> 
  app/views/revisers/_form.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_revisers__form_html_erb___2471522092853631188_70195247159960'
  app/views/revisers/_form.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_revisers__form_html_erb___2471522092853631188_70195247159960'
  app/views/revisers/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_revisers_new_html_erb___1451348464463745171_70195280947160'
```

**reviserController:**

```rails
class RevisersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_reviser, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @reviser = current_user.build_reviser(params[:reviser])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @reviser = current_user.reviser.build(reviser_params)

    if @reviser.save
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "saved...."
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    set_reviser
  end

  def update
    set_reviser
    if @reviser.update(reviser_params)
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "updated.."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private 
  def set_reviser
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
  end

  def reviser_params
    params.require(:reviser).permit(:description, :average_start, :average_end, :max_pages, :price_per, :active)
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that `f.input` isn't a method that exists. Perhaps you meant `f.text_field` or one of the many other [Rails form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)?

Comment: o I see i moved from simple form to this kinda form. So i guess there is no input method.. haha i get it now. i didnt even check cause i just assumed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f.input` isn't defined for the default Rails form helpers. You may be getting confused with the Formtastic/SimpleForm syntax which does use `f.input`.

If you're not using Simple Form or Formtastic, then simply use the standard form helper methods provided by Rails here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

```
<%= f.text_field :description %>
```